# Endomorphisms of Simple A-modules where A is a Complex algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $\underset{=}{\phi} \in End_A S$ is an isomorphism and $S$ is a simple (finite-dimensional?) $A$-module and $A$ is a simple $\mathbb C$-algebra. Then... must we have $\underset{=}{\phi}=\lambda\underset{=}{I}$ ? (This is a coroll. of Schur's Lemma and important lemma for proving Wedderburn's Theorem?)

This is as far as I get;

$\underset{=}{\phi}$ is an $A$-module-homomorphism between simple $A$-modules and thus $\underset{=}{O}$ or an isomorphism by Schur's lemma.

...(stuff)

$\mathbb C$ is a splitting field and thus $\exists\lambda\in\mathbb C$ $m_\underset{=}{\phi}(\lambda)=0$ (Finite-dimensionality of S comes in here?)

Let $T:=\{\underline{v}\in S:\underset{=}{\phi}\underline{v}=\lambda\underline{v}\}$. Vacuously, $\underline{0}\in T$ so $T\neq\varnothing$.

If $\underline{t}_1,\underline{t}_2 \in T$ and $\underset{=}{a}\in A$ then $\underset{=}{\phi}(\underline{t}_1+\underline{t}_2)=\underset{=}{\phi}\underline{t}_1+\underset{=}{\phi}\underline{t}_2=\lambda\underline{t}_1+\lambda\underline{t}_2=\lambda(\underline{t}_1+\underline{t}_2)$ and so $\underline{t}_1+\underline{t}_2\in T$ and $\underset{=}{\phi}(\underset{=}{a}\underline{t}_1)=\underset{=}{a}\underset{=}{\phi}(\underline{t}_1)=\underset{=}{a}\lambda\underline{t}_1=\lambda\underset{=}{a}\underline{t}_1$ and so $\underset{=}{a}\underline{t}_1\in T$

So $T$ is a submodule of $S$ and thus $T\in\{ S,\{ \underline{0} \} \}$

$m_\underset{=}{\phi}(\lambda)=0$, so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\underset{=}{\phi}$ and thus $\exists \underline{v} \in S \setminus \{ \underline{0} \}$ $\underset{=}{\phi}\underline{v}=\lambda\underline{v} $ so $T$ is non-trivial so $T=S$, and thus $\underset{=}{\phi}=\lambda\underset{=}{I}$.

But this gives us an obvious problem - we haven't used Schur's Lemma anywhere! However, we have inadvertently proven a specific example of Schur's lemma for $\mathbb C$-algebrae. Also, we seem to have proven the statement that "If $A$ is a (finite-dimensional?) $\mathbb C$-algebra and $S$ a simple (finite-dimesnional?) $A$-module then $End_A S = \{ \lambda \underset{=}{I} : \lambda \in \mathbb C \}$" which surely cannot be correct?

Comment: Why is this not correct? This is actually the statement of Schur's lemma (to me...).  So what is your version of Schur's lemma?

Comment: Schur's lemma: if $A$ is a $\mathbb K$-algebra and $S, T$ are simple $A$-modules and $\phi : S \rightarrow T $ is a module homomorphism then $\phi = O $ or $\phi$ an isomorphism.

Comment: But this has an independent (and much simpler) proof: $ker \phi$ is a submodule of $S$, and so $ker \phi \in \{ S , \{ 0 \} \} $ so if $\phi$  non-zero then $\phi$ injective. Likewise $ im  \phi $ is a submodule of T so $im  \phi \in \{ T , \{ 0 \} \} $ make so if $ \phi $ is non-zero it is an surjective and thus an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this proves a special case of Schur's lemma, and yes, you need that $S$ is finite-dimensional or else endomorphisms need not have eigenvectors (but no hypothesis on $A$ is necessary other than that it's a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra). Here's the standard proof that uses Schur's lemma: let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $\phi$. Then $\phi - \lambda I$ is either zero or an isomorphism by Schur's lemma. It has nontrivial nullspace, so it can't be an isomorphism, so it's zero.

Be aware that there is more than one result that gets called Schur's lemma, although they're all related. By the general form of Schur's lemma, the endomorphism ring of a simple module is always a division ring (with no extra hypotheses). If $k$ is an algebraically closed field, then the only finite-dimensional division ring over $k$ is $k$ itself (exercise), and this gives the above form of Schur's lemma.

> which surely cannot be correct?

Why?

Comment: Well suppose $A=(M_n \mathbb C)^{op}$ and $M=\mathbb C ^2$

Comment: Well suppose $A=(M_n \mathbb C)^{op}$ and $M=\mathbb C ^2$; then M is simple $A$-module and $A$ a $\mathbb C$-algebra. If $\underset{=}{\phi}(\underline{v})=(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix})\underline{v}$ ; do we then have $\underset{=}{\phi} \in End_A M$ ?

Comment: Your $M$ is not an $A$-module if $n\neq 2$; even so, your $\phi$ is not compatible with $A$-action on $M$, i.e. it is not an $A$-module map.

Comment: @user: I don't follow. The modules over $A$ are all a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{C}^n$, which has endomorphism ring $\mathbb{C}$ as an $A$-module.